# Mule MMC Alert - Url Health check not working for HTTPS

Tags: mule, mule-studio, mule-component, cloudhub

Im creating alert using URL Health check for HTTPS in mule MMC. When I configure Http url works fine. But for HTTPS how can I achieve the health check( https://apps:8089/check), since it is secured connection, there is no option for keystore path where can I place my certificate. Obvious Alert showing me 'SSL handshake error'( Because no where i can configure the certificate) .

How can I configure HTTPS url in MMC( MMC document in Mule also says for HTTP not for HTTPS). Hopefully some way should be there .

Let me know whether it is possible or not, If possible how to achieve the same.Help will be really appreciable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I assume you are running MMC using container such as tomcat, glassfish or jboss. All these containers use JRE/JDK(depending on what you have configured). If you are trying to invoke an HTTPS url from MMC, the relevant certificate(for the HTTPS URL) must be imported into JDK/JRE trust store so that when HTTPS url within MMC is invoked in the JVM(that is running MMC in tomcat/glassfish/jboss), the relevant certificate can be recognized.

Download the certificate from the browser(by clicking on the green bar in browser)

Use this command to import certificate:-
keytool -import -file "Path to your certificate file" -keystore "C:\Program Files\Java\jre7\lib\security\cacerts"

Once done, restart your container and try again.